# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in Controller can't write unknown attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, backend

For one of the views in my rails application, I have set up the controller as such. I want to get all students records from the db and append extra values to each student. This is giving me the error:

**ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in MemoMainTesterController#test_students
can't write unknown attribute `current_target`**

```
class MemoMainTesterController < ApplicationController
  def test_students
    @all_students = Student.all
    @all_students.each do |student|
      current = current_target(student)
      previous_test_info = last_pass(student)
      student[:current_target] = current[0]
      student[:current_level] = current[1]
      student[:current_target_string] = "Level #{current[0]} - Target #{current[1]}"
      student[:last_pass] = previous_test_info[0]
      student[:attempts] = previous_test_info[1]
      student[:last_pass_string] = previous_test_info[2]
    end
  end
.
.
.
end
```

It occurs specifically where `student[:current_target] = current[0]`.

Am I not allowed to append extra values to this hash?
Is there a workaround for this?

EDIT: Although `Student.all` is a model instance, I want to turn it into a hash and append more key value pairs to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `student` is not a Hash but a `Student` model instance.

When you call `student[:current_target]` you are attempting to write Student's `current_target` attribute, which surely is not an actual attribute in the DB for `students` table. Hence the error.

To obtain a hash from your models containing the extra data, you may consider this refactor:

```
class MemoMainTesterController < ApplicationController
  def test_students
    @all_students = Student.all
    @students_with_steroids = @all_students.map do |student|
      current            = current_target(student)
      previous_test_info = last_pass(student)
      student_attributes = student.attributes # <= this is a hash, that you store in student_attributes hash variable

      student_attributes.merge(current_target: current[0], 
        current_level: current[1], 
        current_target_string: "Level #{current[0]} - Target #{current[1]}",
        last_pass: previous_test_info[0],
        attempts: previous_test_info[1],
        last_pass_string: previous_test_info[2])
    end
  end
```

Comment: I don't know what are you actually trying to achieve. Can you update your question?

Comment: Although `Student.all` is a model instance, I want to turn it into a hash and append more key value pairs to it.